# Is JDK 8’s new strategy for dealing with HashMap collisions(tree instead of list) need only for those who is not able to write a good hashcode()?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

> In Java 8, HashMap replaces linked list with a binary tree when the
>   number of elements in a bucket reaches certain threshold

Q: is the mentioned improvement is nothing more but care about those programmers who are not aware how to write an appropriate hashcode() method? Or is it useful in other situations? What are the situations where it's not possible to write good hashcode() method? In other words are there situations where even very good hashcode() method doesn't help against collisions and the tree is viable?

Answer (score 2):

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/a006fa0a9e8f/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l143

> The added complexity of tree bins is worthwhile in providing worst-case O(log n) operations when keys either have distinct hashes or are orderable, Thus, performance degrades gracefully under accidental or malicious usages in which hashCode() methods return values that are poorly distributed, as well as those in which many keys share a hashCode, so long as they are also Comparable.

This improvement prevents denial of service attacks where adversary deliberately picks values which will fall into the same bucket. It's not possible to write hashCode resilient to that, which is also stable between JVM instances.

Answer (score 2):

If you add enough entries to a HashMap, statistically you’re going to get bucket collisions. Note that a bucket collision is *not* the same thing as a hashCode collision; while a hashCode collision always results in a bucket collision, any 2 hashCodes have a <sup>1</sup>/<sub>bucket count</sub> chance of hitting the same bucket.

If by bad luck (many different keys happen to end up in the same bucket) or bad coding (poorly chosen algorithm generates same hashCode for different keys) the number of keys in a bucket grows large, the time complexity of a retrieval *was* O(n), but is now O(log n).

Consider that it is not necessarily *your* hashCode algorithm that is “badly coded”. It could be you are using objects from a 3rd party library for your keys, so this change protects you against other people’s bad code too.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the situations where it's not possible to write good hashcode() method?

Well, apart from the use-cases where someone might trying to DOS you by engineering hash collisions ...

There is the case where a full value-based hashcode calculation is too expensive, so you implement a "cheap and cheerful" version.  But then this version has some edge cases where you get collisions.

An example would be where you used a wrapper for a big array or a tree of hashmaps as a key.  (Clearly there are problems with this approach, but some people will do it anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Your hashCode might not be interpreted the way you think it will in a `HashMap`. 
For example when you create a `HashMap` like:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

There are at least 3 things you should be aware of:

- Only the last 4 bits are taken into consideration to decide what bucket entries will go to.
- A `HashMap` will *re-hash* your hashCode via:

  ```
  static final int hash(Object key) {
      int h;
      return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
  }
  ```
- hashCode is an `int` and it's limited, thus hash collisions are very often. IIRC for `Integer.MAX_VALUE` hash collisions will start around some tens of thousands (44_000? or something similar, can't remember).